# Prove that the Sphere with a Hair in $\mathbb{R} ^{3}$ is not Locally Euclidean at q, hence it can not be a Topological Manifold.

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

> A fundamental theorem of topology, the theorem on invariance of dimension, states that if two nonempty open sets $U ⊂ \mathbb{R} ^{n}$ and $V ⊂ \mathbb{R} ^{m}$ are homeomorphic, then $n = m$. Prove that the sphere with a hair in $\mathbb{R} ^{3}$ is not locally Euclidean at $q$. Hence it cannot be a topological manifold.

I am new to the theory of manifolds, so I have no idea. [image: 1]

Comment: If I understand what you mean by sphere with a hair correctly, a  possible argument would be  that you would disconnect it by removing the root of the hair. Another argument is  that it is connected but has different dimensions at different points...

Comment: I don't think "ball with a hair" is a commonly used English topology space. Is there a definition you can give us for this space? Also, what is $IR^3$?

Comment: There is a sphere as you know. And ıt is connectted with a line which is like a hair. I cannot a put a photo here @GeorgesElencwajg

Comment: Ohh ok sphere with hair is this. @GeorgesElencwajg

Comment: Can you solve this more clearly? I want to learn manifold. But I dont have any idea. Please give me a solution @GeorgesElencwajg

Comment: Do you have any idea? @GeorgesElencwajg

Comment: Dear B11, since your calls for help are quite pressing,  I'll transform one of my hints into a solution [ although I initially lazily hoped that some other user would do that :-)]

Comment: Sorry for my presure. I am new learner of manifold. So I wonder the answer  so much. Thank you. @GeorgesElencwajg

Comment: No problem B11: since I am a teacher,  I actually find your eagerness to learn  quite refreshing!

Comment: Oww really. So good:-)  You can solve good. I understand and imagine something. Thank you again. I am a new math student. So I want to learn solution ways of some problemss which I cannot solve. Sometimes can I disturb for asking a question if nobody solve or I cannot understand the solution? @GeorgesElencwajg

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A connected manifold has a unique dimension $n$, and every point of $X$ then has an open neighbourhood homeomorphic to the open unit  ball  $\mathbb D^n\subset \mathbb R^n$.

However in the pictured $X$ the points different from $q$  on the hair have an open neigbourhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb D^1$ , whereas the points different from $q$  on the sphere have an open neigbourhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb D^2$.

Since $X$ is connected this proves that it is not a manifold, since it cannot have a unique dimension.

Comment: Could you kindly suggest a way to solve this problem using invariance of dimension?

Comment: @RagingBull Georges' proof used invariance of dimension.....

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the neighborhood $U$ of $q$ is homeomorphic to $B(0,r)\subset\mathbb R^n$ with $q$ mapping to $\bf 0$. Since $U-\{q\}$ has two connected components, then $B-\{0\}$ must be of dimension 1. However since $q$ is on a sphere which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^m$, $m>1$, contradiction!
$\square$

---

http://im0.p.lodz.pl/~kubarski/AnalizaIV/Wyklady/L-Tu-1441973990.pdf

You question is taken from p57 of this book. At page 49 the author proved that a cross is not locally Euclidean at the intersect.